# Why error in my neural network first increases and then doesn't change?

Tags: neural-network

I'm using a 2 layered neural network with 7 neurons for hidden layer to predict diabetes. But according to plot that Matlab shows me, my network's error first increases and then doesn't change, while as I know it should first decreases and then stops changing. Is my case possible or my network is not working correctly?

[Error Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmICY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your model's error starts increasing roughly after 50 epochs. It could mean that the model has either overfitted or the dataset you provided is too small for the model to generalize itself. You may follow these tips :

1. Use small learning rates like 0.001 or even 0.0001.
2. Make sure you have a dataset which has a pretty good number of samples.
3. Use Dropout layers. They are excellent in most use-cases. Try keeping a rate of 0.3 or 0.4.
4. Also, if you excessively train a model, it would overshoot the minima and the loss would increase. Experiment an observe that till how many epochs does the network perform well. ( In your case, it might be 25 epochs )

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have another problem which is really bothering me. My network can not predict data, Even data which has trained with them. what type of problem do you think my network has?

Comment: Try posting the code of your network or some description regarding it.